# Remove filters from Date column in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to get the customer age using the first order date with online order type.
The measure is working fine. Problem occures when I filter the month or order type using the slicers.
What I want is no matter which date is selected, the customer age always calculated using the first online order date.
I tried using the removefilter function but it is not working. May be I am not using it correctly.

```
customer-age =
var _firstdate = 
        CALCULATE(
                 FIRSTDATE(Orders[ORDER_CREATED]), 
                 FILTER(
                  Orders,
                  Orders[ORDER_TYPE_NAME] = "ONLINE"))
var _lastdate = TODAY()   
return
DATEDIFF(_firstdate, _lastdate, DAY)
```

Thanks in advance

[PBI and Excel sheet download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GRCJHAnLJDrqGmtumKdkNGT5N_RERw0l/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What happens when you add `REMOVEFILTERS(<Date Table Name>)` to the calculate statement?  This would be the way you would remove any filtering from the date table.

Comment: FIRSTDATE(Orders[ORDER_CREATED]),
REMOVEFILTERS(ORDER[ISSUE_CREATED]),

adding like this do not make any changes in the output. 
For example, when I select June, it takes Junes first online order date to calculate the age, select July and it calculates based on first online order date in July. 

I want this to work as no matter what month or year is selected, it should always calculate the age by taking the first online order date from the date column for every customer.

Comment: So the way you are filtering month is by `Order[Issue_created]`?  Or are you filtering by a date table?

Comment: No, as of now there is not date table. All the fields are within the same table.

Comment: You can download the excel and PBI file here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GRCJHAnLJDrqGmtumKdkNGT5N_RERw0l/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

With new PBIX and Excel file shared by you, I updated my answer:

First Your DAX Code should be like this:

```
customer-age = 
var ordertypepicked =SELECTEDVALUE(Orders[Order Type Name])
var _firstdate = 
        CALCULATE(
                 MIN(Orders[Order Created]), 
                 ALLEXCEPT(Orders,Orders[Customer Name]))
var _lastdate = TODAY()
RETURN
DATEDIFF(_firstdate, _lastdate, DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks Ozan. But it shows age only when all dates are selected from the sliver. Shows no value if only a month is selected from a slicer.

Comment: You're welcome. Please keep in mind that SELECTEDVALUE works by selecting only one value from a slicer. If multiple values are selected, you can define the 2nd parameter as the optional value to be shown. Please share your datasets; so we can test a similar scenario and go back to you sooner.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the details. You can download the excel and PBI file here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GRCJHAnLJDrqGmtumKdkNGT5N_RERw0l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @kmax01 I updated my answer. Please check and test it, and let me know the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I think this is what you are looking for when you are filtering by the month of `ORDER[ISSUE_CREATED]`.  If you are using any other filter, like a date table or the `ORDER_CREATED` column, this will not work.

```
customer-age =
VAR _firstdate =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Orders[ISSUE_CREATED] ),
        FILTER ( Orders, Orders[ORDER_TYPE_NAME] = "ONLINE" ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ( ORDER[ISSUE_CREATED] )
    )
VAR _lastdate =
    TODAY ()
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( _firstdate, _lastdate, DAY )
```

EDIT: please note I switched FIRSTDATE to MIN because FIRSTDATE will fail if there are duplicates.

EDIT 2: based on the file example, I changed the removefilters to work on `ISSUE_CREATED`.  This must be created as a calculated column rather than a measure.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But this one is also not working. I will share a small dataset in excel. Maybe that can help find the solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hi, thanks for the details. You can download the excel and PBI file here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GRCJHAnLJDrqGmtumKdkNGT5N_RERw0l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @kmax01, from the file example, I have changed the code to use removefilters on the column `ISSUE_CREATED`.  This must be created as a calculated column to get the results that you want.  Calculated columns are evaluated when the data is refreshed, rather than when you are interacting with the report so the results will not change when you apply slicers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply as I was offline.

Thank you so much for your help and support. But unfortunately, none of the solutions worked for me :( . The method I used to get the required value is:

step-1:
create a measure to find the minimum value
min-date = calculate(
min(orders[order_created]),
FILTER(
orders, orders[order_type] = "Online")
)

step-2:
create another measure to find days.
datediff ([min-date], today(), day())

step-3:
disable interaction of the date slicer so it won't affect the visual. Format>Edit interaction.

Don't know why the above solutions didn't work but this worked perfectly for me. Thanks anyway.
Pro tips and suggestions are always welcome.